# Making two divs flow under an absolutely positioned div with a fluid layout

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am using a relatively positioned div to contain a slideshow in which the imgs are set to be absolutely positioned. I have two divs that I need to flow after the images. I do not want to use "top" in the CSS, because it creates a giant space when the browser window is resized. The goal is a fluid layout in which the images resize to the browser width.

I have searched exhaustively for the answer, however I am coming up empty handed.

My current situation can be seen here: http://kschassen.com/huberd-design/ If you make the browser window skinny, you will see the large space that is created between the div holding the text and the slideshow above. (A result of using top with a value in the CSS)

Here is what I want the layout to look like, only with the rotating images of course: http://kschassen.com/static-image-website/index-for-testing.html

I am hoping for a simple solution that doesn't require a bunch of scripting, however, I understand that the absolute positioning is the key culprit in this situation. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the JS solution suggested below works when the browser window gets resized, but I need a solution for initial loading. The two lower divs STILL flow up to the top, displaying on top of the div containing the images. Any suggestions?

Comment: The following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/8/ works everywhere except Chrome. Any suggestions for making it work on Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***jQuery solution***

You'll need to move your `.header-container` div above the `.fade-in` div (you would also need to do for the non-js solution)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var fadein = $('.fadein'),
            images = $('.fadein').find('img');

        fadein.css('height', images.height()); // set initial height

        $(window).resize(function(){ //on window resize, set height to height of image
            fadein.css('height', images.height());
        });
    });
</script>
```

***original non-js solution***

If you don't want to use a script, the only way I've come up with to make divs with absolute images inside responsive is to add another element inside that has `position: relative; visibility: hidden;` along with all the same size properties. If all your images are the same size, just duplicate one of them.

Where you have four images like so:

```
<img src="images-large/pollack-north.jpg" alt="English country style home built by Huberd Design" style="display: block;">
```

Add a div below them with this same image inside set to `position: relative; visibility: hidden;`

```
<div class="create-height">
    <img src="images-large/pollack-north.jpg" style="visibility: hidden; position: relative;">
</div>
```

Here's a **[codepen](http://codepen.io/brouxhaha/pen/rhjbd)** where I use this functionality. It adds an extra element (or 2), but you can forego the javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however it doesn't work for my situation. Putting in another div makes the fixed nav bar disappear and still creates a large space between the image slide show and the text area.

Comment: I am not opposed to a javascript solution, just don't want to add unneeded complexity. Do you know a javascript solution?

Comment: Looks like the script is pulling the image out of the div - it would require changing the script to only grab certain images (preferably with a class). I'll look into a js solution here quick.

Comment: Thank you so much! The js solution did the trick! Your help saves my design. Happy Thanksgiving.

Comment: Update - it works in IE 9 and 10 and Firefox on Mac. Works in Chrome if I resize the window, but not on initial load. Having an issue still with iOS Safari where it doesn't stack correctly. Think I will also try the hidden element that is relatively positioned, but put it inside the fadein div.

Comment: I see you've put the code in your header. Try putting it right before your closing body tag (after your last script tag).

Comment: Or you can combine the two sets of code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/1/ I think when you hide the images, it's affecting the initial setting of the height.

Comment: Your follow up is appreciated. I've tried putting both code sets together, separately and at the beginning and end of the document, however nothing seems to solve the "initial load" problem. The solution works when the window is resized, but in Safari and Chrome the content div STILL loads on top of the images. Is there a way to "tell" the containing div to be the size of the image on document load?

Comment: Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/2/. This sets the div height before you hide the images. If that still doesn't work, let's go into chat - there are a few other things we can do.

Comment: Unfortunately, now it is worse than before. The resize function doesn't work in Chrome/Safari and it creates a spacing issue in Firefox. I am available to chat if you are.

Comment: Apparently, chat is only for users over 20 rep, so let's try this: http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/4/. It helps when I update all the code (the resize works now). Here I'm using a function to hide the images which is called after we set the height. If that doesn't work (because apparently jsfiddle is not reacting like the browser in your case), try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/5/. Here I'm putting a slight delay before hiding the images.

Comment: Made a change to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/8/. Still doesn't work on Chrome, though. Thoughts?

Comment: Everything is working in Chrome for me, so I'm not sure what's causing the issue.

Comment: Looks like there is a delay in me seeing your comments....the resize function works perfectly. In fact, when I load the page locally in Chrome, it renders correctly as well. It is also rendering correctly on load in Chrome on the PC. The problem seems to be with Chrome on the Mac. Again, resize makes the page render correctly, but initially, the rendering shows content div on top of the images. I cannot replicate this issue in jsfiddle. Do you know any reason Chrome Mac would behave this way?

Comment: Alright, I think I've figured this out: in Chrome, the images aren't loaded before the jQuery runs, so there are no images on `$(document).ready()`. So change that to `$(window).load()`. You'll see a bit of a flash while everything loads, but you can take care of that by setting the images to `visibility: hidden;` in the css, then changing that in the jQuery. This fiddle isn't working because of the `$(window).load()` change, but it works locally.

Comment: OK, YES, the change to $(window).load() in the script for determining the height is now working in Chrome. To stop the "flickering", if I understand you correctly, I should put visibility:hidden on the class for the images, however I am unsure how to "change" that in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, which fiddle? Don't see the change in the fiddles posted in above comments. Also, would love to give you credit in my code on for your solution. What should I include?

Comment: Sorry, apparently I never pasted it into the comment I meant to: http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/10/.

Comment: OK, great, thanks. When I changed to the script in the fiddle and added the visibility:hidden to the CSS, everything works EXCEPT it is only showing the first image in the series. I see you "cleaned up" the script. Did something get taken out or modified that would have affected the other images dissolving in?

Comment: Looks that way. Here's a complete working version - this one has $(document).ready() to show it's working, so just keep $(window).load() and you're set (I hope). http://jsfiddle.net/2zU4b/11/